# How to set user account flag WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT in Active Directory using powershell script?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, user-accounts

I am trying to set `WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT` (0x1000) flag using a PowerShell command

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305144

I searched and found the `Set-ADAccountControl` command..
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617249.aspx

But in MSDN it is not written how to set `0x1000`.

How to set `WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT` flag using PowerShell command?

They have following flags:

```
AccountNotDelegated
AllowReversiblePasswordEncryption
AuthType
CannotChangePassword
Credential
DoesNotRequirePreAuth
Enabled
HomedirRequired
MNSLogonAccount
Partition
PassThru
PasswordNeverExpires
PasswordNotRequired
Server
TrustedForDelegation
TrustedToAuthForDelegation
UseDESKeyOnly
Confirm
WhatIf
```

EDIT :

```
C# code 
following is my C# code which is throwing error access denied.

const int iFlag = 0x1000;
string sCommonName = "CN=" + sMachineName;

DirectoryEntry deComputer = deOU.Children.Add(sCommonName, "computer");
deComputer.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value = sMachineName + "$";
deComputer.CommitChanges();

deComputer.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = iFlag;
deComputer.CommitChanges(); // access denied exception.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it:

```
$accountName = "userLogin"

$adsiSearcher = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher [ADSI]$null
$adsiSearcher.filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=$accountName))"

$adsiSearcherResult = $adsiSearcher.FindOne()
$user = $adsiSearcherResult.GetDirectoryEntry()

if(($user.UserAccountControl[0] -band 4096) -ne 0) {

    "WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT (0x1000 4096) is set for $accountName"

} else {

    "WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT (0x1000 4096) is NOT set for $accountName"

    # Add the useraccountdisabled flag (decimal value 4096)
    $user.userAccountControl[0] += 4096

    # Save the new value in the user object
    $user.SetInfo()

    "WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT (0x1000 4096) has been added for $accountName"
}
```

Source: https://knowledge.zomers.eu/PowerShell/Pages/How-to-control-UserAccountControl-Active-Directory-flags-with-PowerShell.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried the script but getting adsiSearcherResult as null.

Comment: I put directly username as   $user = [ADSI] "LDAP://CN=Koen Zomers,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=local" and getting error "A device attached to the system is not functioning"

Comment: On my system, `$adsiSearcher` remains `$null` if the user login is incorrect.

Comment: My code flow is like this .I have created the user, then trying to set trust account then password. user created successfully. trust account result into access denied result. hence i was trying to set this trust account flag by script. any clue why it was given access denied error. other flag I can set by set-adusercontrol command? Where can I see if user created successfully?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what command produced an access denied error, along with the error message ? I don't understand your last question, `Get-ADUser -Filter *` should list your account if it exists.

Comment: I was trying to set WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT using powershell if I can proceed.