# Why I am getting "A device attached to the system is not functioning" error even though machine name exist?(Active Directory)

Tags: powershell, active-directory, user-accounts

I have computer name = xyz

I run the following script to set usercontrol flag.

```
$accountName = "xyz";

$user  = [ADSI] "LDAP://CN=xyz,OU=TestOS,DC=domain,DC=net"
Write-Host $user
if(($user.UserAccountControl[0] -band 4096) -ne 0) {
"WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT (0x1000 4096) set for $accountName"

} else {

    "WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT (0x1000 4096) is NOT set for $accountName"

    # Add the useraccountdisabled flag (decimal value 4096)
    $user.userAccountControl[0] += 4096

    # Save the new value in the user object
    $user.SetInfo()

    "WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT (0x1000 4096) has been added for $accountName"
}
```

but getting output as

> Exception calling "SetInfo" with "0" argument(s): "A device attached to the system is not functioning.

I searched and found out if computer name doesn't exit these error will be thrown.

But I am able to get details using following command.

```
 Get-ADComputer "xyz" -Properties *
```

Why I am getting "A device attached to the system is not functioning" error even though machine name exist?

Comment: Isn't `$user` supposed to be a *user* and not a *computer* ?

Comment: How can I modify above script to set user control flag for machine name=xyz?

Comment: As far as I could read, this kind of flags *control the behavior of the Microsoft Active Directory **user** account*

Comment: if you see my question edit section http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34216863/how-to-set-user-account-flag-workstation-trust-account-in-active-directory-using , I am trying to set the flag using C# code but getting access denied. So I am trying to do it with powershell to check if I get same error. Can you help me on this how to sort out this problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97850/discussion-between-suri-and-sodawillow).

Comment: any solution ? ***sAMAccountName maxlength*** 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095510/creating-a-user-in-active-directory-a-device-attached-to-the-system-is-not-func